# "I have 2 Litres fuel in my car" " I drink 1 litre water in a day""

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, american-english, british-english, sentence-choice

Is word "of" compulsory in a sentences "I have 2 litres of fuel in my car" " I drink 1 litre of water daily" or can i say these sentences with out using "of" as in

"I have 2 litres fuel in my car"
"I drink 1 litre water in a day"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes,** the "of" is compulsory, and your example sentences sound unnatural.

We always connect a measurement to a noun with "of" whether it's specific or abstract. This can only be omitted when you are counting the nouns rather than measuring them.

- I have *two liters* **of** *fuel* in my car.
- There are *plenty* **of** *fish* in the sea.
- I bought *four loaves* **of** *bread* this morning.
- I also bought *seven cupcakes*. (No "of" needed here, since we are counting the cupcakes individually!)